# Web application backend authentication and interaction

Tags: jquery, api, authentication, go

I'm currently writing a Web application backend in Go. What is the best way to make some kind of API available for a standard jQuery AJAX frontend to interact with my backend?

Right now, I have some functions that accept some data, perform operations, and return other data, but where exactly should I go from there? I have a vague idea of listening in on some port for a JSON-encoded function call and returning the JSON-encoded output of that function, but (if this is a good way of accomplishing this) what is the best way of accomplishing this?

Furthermore, how exactly should I handle a login system and/or authentication with Go/AJAX? Would it make sense to return some unique hash key for that user, (save it to a cookie if persistent login is selected,) store that key in memory, and send that key as a parameter of every JSON-encoded function call sent to the server? Or, is there a better way of accomplishing this (I'm not knowledgeable on login systems) or possibly a solution already developed for Go?

Comment: http://buu700.com/sampleapi -- sample of the functions which I would have behind the AJAXy/JSONy API layer.

Comment: Have you heard of `web.go` or the go app-engine SDK? Do you have a server running?

Comment: I've seen web.go's page, but haven't looked a lot into it; does it add a lot more over the `http` package? I have my own server running, so I won't be using GAE at all.

Comment: @Elazar Leibovich: web.go doesn't have session cookies (cookies that get deleted after you shut down your browser). That's a big minus for such a task.

Answer (score 1):

[Goajax](https://github.com/jeffreybolle/goajax) is a JSON-RPC package for go. The style is somewhat you pass it function names and parameters via JSON, and it returns JSON as answer.

Personally though, I prefer [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)-services. REST uses standard web technologies, especially HTTP and URI for passing resources and what to do on them. JSON is very efficient for this as well. For a REST-service, there is the [rest.go](http://github.com/nathankerr/rest.go) library (also, a [fork](https://github.com/Kissaki/rest.go)).

For authentification, you may want to look at [authcookie](http://github.com/dchest/authcookie). "implements creation and verification of signed authentication cookies."

Using an auth-hash via cookie (or param as alternative) is a common way. Make sure you are aware though, that you make them secure. Use HTTPS to prevent eavesdropping (WLANs, pub-nets, man-in-the-middles). How you first validate them depends on what you’re actually doing. Also make sure to think about session lifetimes.